# Using new style signal and slots for combobox?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qcombobox, qt-signals

I have two lines using the old SIGNAL and SLOT style..

```
combobox.emit(SIGNAL("activated(int)"), combobox.currentIndex())
combobox.emit(SIGNAL("activated(const QString &)"), combobox.currentText())
```

I was wondering what the new style would look like. I'm new to python and I don't have much experience with signals and slots. Is there a really good resource floating around that covers this? The documentation didn't really help me understand what was going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to indicate the type of argument of the signal that is being emitted:

```
combo.activated[type].connect(someSlot)
```

Example:

```
class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        combo = QComboBox(self)
        self.layout().addWidget(combo)
        combo.addItems(["item1", "item2", "item3"])
        combo.activated[int].connect(self.onActivatedIndex)
        combo.activated[str].connect(self.onActivatedText)

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def onActivatedIndex(self, index):
        print(index)

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def onActivatedText(self, text):
        print(text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Is there any reason to use connect vs emit in this case?

Comment: Connect vs emit are 2 complementary things, when you use connect is to create the connection between the signal and the slot, instead when the signal executes emit you are telling the PyQt that you have to call all the slots that were previously connected to the signal. Therefore there is no versus between connect and emit.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding this, if I have several signals connected to a slot, and I want to update all of those, the I would use emit?

Comment: the signals are not updated, the slots are updated, you call emit to invoke the slots connected to the signal.

Comment: Read the following so you understand the logic of the signals and slots: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html

Comment: Got it I think. Hopefully this will be my last question, am I correct to assume that emit is not being used in this example, or is it implied in the activated[] part of the statement?

Comment: there are 2 signals that are called activated created by QComboBox, in the example we are connecting to the 2 slots respectively, the class QComboBox each time you select a new item emits signals internally. I recommend you first read the documentation, it is uncomfortable answering questions without you trying to study.